# Is magnetic resonance microscopy appropriate for investigating ion-channel flow?

Tags: neurophysiology

I've been looking into ways to characterize the elecrophisiology of neurons for cell signaling and I came across magnetic resonance microscopy as a tool for gaining images of neuronal activiy at a large scale.

This made me question, is it possibly to take a timeseries video of an active neuron and view the actual signal flow through and outside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clarification**

I am unclear of your aim. What feature of elecrophisiology do you want to characterize?
What do you mean by large scale? E.g. Micrometers (μm),  Milimeters (mm) or Centimetres (cm).
Magnetic resonance microscopy imagings at Micrometers (μm).

**Answer**

An established way to observe neuron propagation is the use of calcium imaging. You can take a video under a fluorescent microscope to observe (Not measure) elecrophisiology. Also I believe this technique may provide the 'larger scale' you are seeking.

More On Calcium Imaging:
https://www.cell.com/neuron/comments/S0896-6273(12)00172-9

Comment: Ah I wasn't aware of calcium imaging I will look into it. To clarify yes, I wanted to know if it is possible to inspect/observe signal propagation through a single neuron.

Comment: Excellent, I admire your curiosity.